# Building GDAL / Sqlite3 Issue: undefined reference to `sqlite3_column_table_name'

Tags: r, sqlite, gdal, rgdal

I've run into a brick wall building GDAL on Centos 7. I'm trying to build :

- R 4.2.3
- Geos 3.8.0
- Proj 7.2.0
- GDAL 3.2.0

It fails on GDAL. The error looks like this:

```
#14 2010.5 /bin/sh /tmp/gdal-3.2.0/libtool --mode=link --silent g++  gdalinfo_bin.lo  /tmp/gdal-3.2.0/libgdal.la  -o gdalinfo
#14 2010.7 /tmp/gdal-3.2.0/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `sqlite3_column_origin_name'
#14 2010.7 /tmp/gdal-3.2.0/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `sqlite3_column_table_name'
#14 2010.7 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
#14 2010.8 make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/gdal-3.2.0/apps'
#14 2010.8 make[1]: *** [gdalinfo] Error 1
#14 2010.8 make: *** [apps-target] Error 2
#14 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c cd /tmp &&    VERSION=3.2.0 &&    wget https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/releases/download/v${VERSION}/gdal-${VERSION}.tar.gz &&    tar -xvf gdal-${VERSION}.tar.gz &&    cd gdal-${VERSION} &&    ./configure --with-proj=/usr/local &&    make &&    make install &&    cd .. &&    rm -rf gdal-${VERSION} gdal-${VERSION}.tar.gz]: exit code: 2
```

I had to install sqlite3 from source since it's not available for centos 7 at a recent enough version. When I do this, I add a macro which I thought should fix this:

```
CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA=1 -SQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA=1" && \
./configure && \
```

But that makes no difference. N.B added 2 flags as unsure of spelling.

How to fix this?